# What would you like to call our chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

We have the possibility of editing the Chat channel's name... What name would you propose?

- One name per answer.
- Make it original!
- If in Russian, the better!

The description can be changed too, but I think it's best to keep it in English so the other users can search the channel even if they don't know Russian or don't have a Russian keyboard/layout.

Comment: I don't understand what a chat channel is and what is its purpose, can you please explain it in your post?

Comment: Sure. For example, [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3764/russian-language-and-usage) is our main Chat Room. We can change its name. Other sites did... So why not us? :D

Comment: And where is it?

Answer (score 2):

**Избушка на курьих ножках.**

It is the name of the house of the forest witch Баба Яга from Russian folk tales. Literally, it means ["a wooden house on chicken legs"](http://www.google.com/imgres?hl=ru&client=ubuntu&hs=t4H&sa=X&channel=fs&biw=1600&bih=702&tbm=isch&prmd=imvns&tbnid=22AtDF6mD6embM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.free-lance.ru/users/molly-s/viewproj.php?prjid=714822&docid=S2udYuMg5YLRqM&imgurl=http://st.free-lance.ru/users/molly-s/upload/f_4969c1d45af45.jpg&w=383&h=425&ei=aIsaUKaMM8zesgaZiYHADw&zoom=1).

Answer (score 1):

**Вече**

It's the name of a Slavic council, when people all gathered together to make laws and resolve arguments. It is also the name of the highest legislature and judicial authority in Novgorod until 1478, as Wikipedia says.

Comment: I like the conciseness of `Вече`, and the historical aspect is a nice touch too.

Answer (score 0):

**Арбат**

A famous pedestrian street in historical Moscow and.